# AJAX load more button returns the same posts every time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, lazy-loading

AJAX load more returns the same posts every time. Issue is in WP_Query because this code works when I remove it. I can't figure it out what is wrong with my WP_Query.

This is part of index.php

```
$category_id = get_cat_ID('Događaji');
        $exlude_latest_featured_post = array($featuredID);
        $args = array(
            'category__not_in' => array($category_id),
            'post__not_in' => $exlude_latest_featured_post,
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
        );

        $main_loop = new WP_Query ( $args );
        while ($main_loop->have_posts()) : $main_loop->the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part('loop/content'); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <div class="listing-more-posts">
            <a>
               <?php
                   $link_label = '<img class="listing-more-posts-image" src="'. get_bloginfo('template_directory') .'/images/more-posts-2.gif" alt="Učitaj još postova">';
                   next_posts_link($link_label);
               ?>
            </a>
        </div>
```

This is my loadmore.js file. As I said, it works fine when I remove WP_Query in index.php

```
jQuery(function($){

// Ajax (next) page load
    var pageLoading = false;
    function loadContent($link){

        if( pageLoading == true ){
            return;
        }

        pageLoading = true;

        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: $link.attr("href"),
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(response){
                var html = $('<div>').html(response);

                // 'standard' blog layout
                var $articles = $(html).find("#post-listing article");

                //$("#main").append(articles);
                $link.closest(".listing-more-posts").before($articles);

                // remove old nav wrapper (new one is added with new content)
                // if( $link != null ){
                $link.closest(".listing-more-posts").html($(html).find(".listing-more-posts").html());
                // }

                pageLoading = false;
            }
        });
    }

      $("body").on("click", ".listing-more-posts a", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("click");

        // var $link = $(this);
        $(this).parent().addClass('loading');
        loadContent($(this));
    });  
});
```

I was searching for answer but couldn't find it. From the answers I found so far I think I need to do something with tracking page number, but I am not sure how to do that.

Thank you

Comment: Take a copy of $link or create a closure

Comment: Thanks mplungjan for trying to help me, but I am still not sure what I have to do. Can you describe it to me a little better please. Thanks

Comment: Try first `function loadContent($aLink){ var $link = $aLink;`

Comment: Thanks mplungjan once again. Unfortunately that doesnt work. Still having the same posts load every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

I was breaking main loop by doing things from above. I countinued to search and after some time I found one really useful action hook called per_get_posts and that was solution for my problem

> This hook is called after the query variable object is created, but
>   before the actual query is run. 
> - Wordpress Codex

All what I had to do now was this two things:

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $category_id = get_cat_ID('Događaji');
            $query->set( 'category__not_in', array($category_id) );
        }
    }
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
//Exclude latest featured post from showing in loop
function exclude_latest_post( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $exlude_latest_featured_post = array($featuredID);
            $query->set( 'post__not_in', $exlude_latest_featured_post );
        }
    }
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_latest_post' );
```